# How to integrate swagger documentation on resteasy 3?

Tags: swagger, resteasy

I have resteasy 3 rest web-services for which I want to add swagger documentation. I'm using Maven. I found many tutorials for jersey and spring but not for resteasy.

Answer (score 0):

I created a example https://github.com/diegogusava/togus

This class do all the work: https://github.com/diegogusava/togus/blob/master/togus-rest/src/main/java/br/com/diegogusava/togus/infrastructure/RestConfiguration.java

Comment: As far as I understand where goes the steps:
1- Add swagger 3 dependencies on togus/togus-rest/pom.xml
      1.1- Define the package where the rest calls are

2- Config the swagger bean br.com.diegogusava.togus.infrastructure .RestConfiguration.java
3- Add swagger UI on

Comment: 3- Add swagger UI on webapp folder

I access {baseUrl}/swagger I have the default swagger UI page

I still missing the trick how to connect my app calls to the swagger UI

Comment: I can access swagger url but I only see the example page (it seams that is not generating the swagger.json/yaml file...) Where in the code this file should be generated?